# Port security blocked the port permanently - Beginner

Tags: networking, cisco

I enabled Port Security on the switch.

```
> conf t
> int fa 0/3
> switchport mode access 
> switchport port-security maximum 1
> switchport port-security mac sticky
```

And to test if this works, i connected a cable to this port and pinged, then the port got blocked as expected.

Now i reconnected the original desktop (the one which was connected before- the one which is suppose to work with this port). and I am unable to ping by connecting to this port.

I think, the port is, and i am not allowed to plug in even the PC (that i am suppose to plugin). So how can i make this work (Bring the port up for the port 0/3 which will work for the mac address i assigned previously)

note: i am using packet tracer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/security/command/reference/sec_s6.html#wp1060275)

```
switchport port-security violation {shutdown | restrict | protect}
```

The default violation policy (what happens when violation is detected) is "shutdown" port. You can try setting this to `protect`, or you have to manualy reenable the port (`no shutdown` on the interface).

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the global command "errdisable recovery cause psecure-violation".  This would cause the port to unlock itself after 5 minutes (by default).  Of course, if you still have the offending non-secure device plugged in the port will lock itself again =)

Comment: Could anyone tell me the purpose of adding `switchport port-security maximum 1` ? (I know that this is not relevant to this post, but i'm curious to know)

Comment: It is the number of allowed macs on that port. If there is a pc connected to the port, then you allow only one mac on that port (that is the default). If there is a switch/hub on that port, you need to allow more then 1 mac (all the macs on the connected switch).